# No Internet connection with Static IP - windows10

Tags: networking, ip

Desktop running Win10 x64, with two ethernet cards, plus wifi. This is on a home network with router set to do the DHCP duty, address range 100 to 199. Numerous devices exist on the network via fixed and DHCP IP addresses, via WiFi and wired connections. All operate ok. Norton 360 is my Anti most things protection.

When I try to set the Desktop to a static IP address (e.g. .200) it connects to the network but not to the internet. I have tried both ethernet cards and the WiFi but none will connect to the internet as a fixed IP and the Win10 troubleshooter keeps telling me the same error "DHCP is not enabled for ....". Obviously this is not a "fix" I want.
Rebooted router and desktop many times, changed the selected IP address, disabled and enabled the adaptors, but it just does not work. WTF?????

Answer (score 4):

I think perhaps you left out DNS.  Set the Static IP, Mask, and Gateway (which is your Router main address). Then set DNS as the same addresses used by your router. As soon as you enter DNS and save, you should see Internet.

[image]

Comment: Thanks John, that worked! Just a short delay before internet was ok.Wish I had asked sooner instead of wasting hours.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
After a power outage, my desktop couldn't connect with its usual manually configured IP number anymore.

```
ipconfig /all
```

showed xx.xx.xx.xx(duplicate)
It worked when I enabled DHCP on Windows.

What happened was, that the manual number collided with the IP pool of the DHCP server. It was pure luck it worked before. After I changed the pool to x.x.x.100-x.x.x.254 and a restart of DHCP server and clients everything worked fine.